# Single input endpoint can be accessed in different worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a input endpoint(name - 23456), Can i access the 23456 endpoint into different worker role?

For eg :- In "23456" endpoint, i have this data's **23,34,45,56,78**.

**Worker roles** - "A" and "B"

When i access the endpoint through "A" worker role, i will get 23 as values. When i access the endpoint through "B" worker role, What value i will get 34 or 23?

I could like to understand the working flow of input endpoint. Please help me to understand.

Comment: How is this question related to both AWS and Azure Storage?

Comment: its related to azure cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Input endpoints are load-balanced across all instances of a web role or worker role.

If you want direct access to a given instance, you need to create *input instance endpoints* instead. Details may be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances/#instance-input-endpoint).

Note: The fact that you're seeing different data depending on which role instance you're visiting means you're storing data on the instance itself, instead of a global resource (such as a database or cache). Data stored on individual role instances is at risk, since it's non-durable storage (unless you're using attached disks). And even if you're using attached disks, your data will become unavailable during any time your role instance is recycled.

Comment: Thanks David. Can i assume like, i can access an endpoint in different worker role parallel and i will get the similar data in both worker role?